# How to enable user via LDAP in AD?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

In my program (jldap-based) I trying to enable user in AD by setting userAccountControl value to 512.
User created with following attributes:

```
objectClass=user
cn=username
name=username
userAccountControl=512
userPassword={BASE64}<base64 encoded password>
sAMAccountName=username
distinguishedName=username,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com
```

But I get exception:

```
LDAPException: Unwilling To Perform (53) Unwilling To Perform
LDAPException: Server Message: 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A0FC0, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

May be anybody can tell me where I'm making an error? Maybe I forgot some required attribute?

EDIT:

My code (It is trivial and I think that no errors in it):

```
LDAPConnection connection;
LDAPMessageQueue messageQueue;
...
LDAPAttributeSet attributes = new LDAPAttributeSet();
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("objectClass", "user"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("cn", "username"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("name", "username"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("userAccountControl", "512"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("userPassword", "{BASE64}<base64 encoded password>"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("sAMAccountName", "username"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("distinguishedName", "username,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com"));

LDAPEntry entry = new LDAPEntry("CN=username,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com", attributes);
connection.add(entry);
```

Comment: Please show some code as how you are setting these values. Maybe there is an error in it.

Comment: I not think, that error in code, because I can create disabled user, but when I try to enable user I receive exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can arise when the password is not correctly encoded. Make sure it's a Base64 encoded UTF-16LE string.

Example (if you are using Oracle JVM)

```
String pass = "password";
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
String encoded = enc.encode(pass.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

UPDATE 1:
Have you tried running your code without the userAccountControl attribute (to rule in or out that it's actually that attribute that is causing problems)?

I noticed that your distinguished name attribute looks a bit strange, as well. It should probably look something like `CN=username,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com`.

UPDATE 2: see [Adding a user with a password in Active Directory LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322243/how-to-add-user-with-password-in-ldap). WILL_NOT_PERFORM can be returned if you are trying to set password for an entry (which you are, since you're creating it) over a non-SSL connection. You need to make sure you are connecting to the AD server over SSL (and set up certificates as required).

Comment: Thanks you, but when I trying your example I get some exception.

Comment: Which exception? The same as before? Please post the code of how you create/update your user.

Comment: Yes, exception is same as before. I added my code in question.

Comment: Thanks, I did mistake when write code example. In real world application I set distinguished name in right format. And thanks you for note about SSL - I think it's source of my problem.